# How to check null or datetime value using ternary operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ternary-operator

I want to check passed value is null or datetime value using ternary operator in c#?

I tried like this

```
fromDate == null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
```

getting error:

```
type of conditional expression cannot be determined
```

I want to check whether variable `fromDate` is null or having date time value ?

> variable  fromDate is coming from Querystring and type of string.

Comment: What is wrong with `TryParseExact`?

Comment: Do you know the date time format?

Comment: The datatype of the variable you are assigning to needs to be Nullable and cast null to type Nullable DateTime. When reading a nullable date from a database, we typically do the following; `DateTime? myDate = rdr.IsDBNull(ADDRESSENDDATE_ORDINAL) ? (DateTime?)null : rdr.GetDateTime(ADDRESSENDDATE_ORDINAL);` You'd need to do something similar.

Comment: what is fromDate? is it string or DateTime?

Comment: you might want to use default(DateTime). Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`?: Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) returns `DateTime` and there is no *implicit conversion* between `null` and `DateTime`. And the *conditional operator* is an expression and that needs a return type.

One option seems logical to me using `DateTime.TryParse` (which returns `boolean`) as a *first expression* and use another boolean (`true` or `false`) as a *second expression*. [Damiths' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821906/447156) seems logical.

Or instead you can use nullable DateTime like `DateTime?`

```
DateTime? foo;

if(foo.HasValue)
{
   //Nullable DateTime has a value..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have string value for `fromDate` do as below

```
DateTime dt;

bool isValidDate =  String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate) ? false : DateTime.TryParse(fromDate, out dt);
```

if you know the datetime format/formats which your input having you better use `DateTime.TryParseExact` method

if fromDate is DateTime, then simple you can check as below

```
fromDate.HasValue
```

you don't need `?: Operator`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) is of type DateTime, which cannot accept a null value, that is why this code won't work in this form. You have two choices to make. Either change it to regular if:

```
if(fromDate != null)
{
        Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
}
```

Or cast DateTime to nullable DateTime:

```
    fromDate == null ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
```

Ternary operator in C# needs both values to be of the same type and it is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0173).

Answer (score -1):

```
romDate == null ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
```

`null` and `Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)` haven't common type. Compiler must be able to cast both expressions in canditional operator to same type.

Comment: need to check for same variable and convert into datetime to that variable ? why 2 different variables used ? plz explain

Answer (score -1):

you must use String.IsNullOrEmpty to check if fromDate is null like this:

```
DateTime? date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDte) ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
```

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` returns a bool, and as Hamlet has stated, this isn't the problem

Comment: why different variables fromDte , fromDate ?

Comment: the problem that DateTime cannot be given a null value, you must use nullable DateTime

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will help you

```
   string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
    DateTime dateTime;

    fromDate=(DateTime.TryParseExact(fromDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))?dateTime:null;
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the main problem is that you are trying to assign `null` to a `DateTime`

DateTime is a structure and not a reference type so this can't be done.

Either use a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) or a specific value to indicate null, such as `DateTime.MinValue`

Have a look here for an example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime